# How to integrate Avangate with Geckoboard?

Tags: node.js, web-services, analytics, geckoboard

I am creating a dashboard in Geckoboard with data coming in from Avangate. I will be using IPN to display total number of buys on the dashboard.

From Geckoboard side, I understand that I would be creating a custom widget with relevant data format.

I am not clear on the Avangate side as I can hardly find any documentation. It seems like it should be a web service but couldn't find any thing relevant on Google or their site.

It would be great if some one can point to a example or can share their own experience in designing this integration.

I have found some online data on Avangate IPN but I am not able to figure out what is happening with this code.

https://github.com/callmewa/avangate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find IPN documentation in your Avangate account (https://secure.avangate.com/cpanel/help.php?view=topic&topic=345). We’re working on an updated version for our public portal: https://developer.avangate.com/.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the input. I saw your API 3.0, it looks good. It would be great if you can publish a small video or a working app hosted some where which gives a better understanding of steps to be followed. I can understand the code, I just have difficulty understanding the steps to be followed.